# How to initialize an array instance of the class within it self?

Tags: c++

I want to be able to create an array of Nodes, within a constructor of Node. However i am getting some kind of heap error.

I wrote a Node class with a constructor trying to instantiate Node array with new.

```
 class Node 
 {
   private:
     Node* nodes;
     int max_size;
     int current_size;
   public:
     Node()
     {
       max_size = 10;
       current_size = 0;
       nodes = new Node[max_size]; // Error is here*
     }
 };
```

I am hoping to create an object that creates 10 instances of that object within a constructor. As I am writing this i realized that this will create an infinite loop. Those 10 will create another 10 each, and so on. How should i go about solving this? Should i make a double pointer?

Comment: Sure that would call the `Node` constructor recursively as `new` is supposed to do.

Comment: Since to "create an object that creates 10 instances of that object within a constructor" there is no way to do that without running into infinite loop... Please stop, think about what you actually want and then [edit] question to clarify.

Comment: The only sensible option to avoid endless recursion is to delay creating the array until after the constructor has exited.

Comment: If the assignment permits, consider using a `std::vector<Node>` in place of the `Node*`. It will make whole families of potential bugs just go away.

Comment: sorry its not an assignment, I was just writing random code. I felt like i wanted to create an Node object that could be connected to another Node. And that Node can be connected back to the original Node. For instance node A can be connected to N number of nodes and to itself. Then those nodes can be connected to N number of nodes new and previous. And then using any node i was trying to iterate through all connected nodes using the address of those nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try to instantiate new Node objects in the Node constructor you will keep making recursive calls to the constructor and run out of memory. You are trying to create a node, which creates 10 nodes, and each of those create 10 nodes, and so on.

If you want to just allocate space for `max_size` nodes, you will need to use a double pointer if you don't want to use `std::vector`.

```
class Node {
private:
    Node** nodes;
    ...
public:
    // Constructor
    Node() {
        ...
        nodes = new Node*[max_size];
    }
};
```

Outside the constructor you can populate that array with new Node objects through a separate function.